# alterando o css das pseudoclasses de elementos com jquery é possível?

Tags: jquery, css, seletores

Estou fazendo alguns testes com `jquery` e, me veio a seguinte questão:

**É possível manipular os pseudoelementos de classes `css` com o `jquery`?**

```
$('#login_1').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($('#principal-modais').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('#principal-modais').css({'display':'inline-block'});
        $('html').addClass('modais-ativos');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.modais-ativos:after').css({'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,.7)'});
            $('#principal-modais').css({'opacity':1});
        },100);
    }
});
$('#fecha-modais').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($('#principal-modais').css('display') != 'none') {
        $('#principal-modais').css({'opacity':0});
        $('.modais-ativos:after').css({'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,0)!important'});
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#principal-modais').css({'display':'none'});
            $('html').removeClass('modais-ativos');
        },1000);
    }
});
```

Então realizei o código acima como teste, porém sem sucesso, caso seja possível acessar os seletores dos elementos/classes, como poderia ser feito ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode manipular porquê tecnicamente psudoclasses não é uma parte do DOM, então é inacessível pelo javascript. Existem outras formas para fazer isso, várias delas listadas [aqui](https://pankajparashar.com/posts/modify-pseudo-elements-css/), eu particularmente prefiro e uso o método 1, onde é usado classes separadas e no momento da alteração fazer um *toggle* das classes:

**HTML**

```
<span class="modais-ativos preto">
```

**CSS**

```
.preto::after {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
}
.outro-preto::after{
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7)
}
```

**Javascript**

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.modais-ativos').removeClass('preto').addClass('outro-preto');
},100);
```

Referência do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery).